# .is(":hidden") detects element as visible after .hide("slow")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was hoping to construct a function that readjusts the appearance of one div depending on visibility of the other (via .is(":hidden")) - without introducing additional variables.
This works well when I am using .hide() instead of .hide("slow"). In the latter case, the check detects it as visible if initiated immediately.
Example:

```
$('#1').hide("slow");

//...

if($("#1").is(':hidden'))
{
    //do something with #2
}
```

Above works well if I do not use "slow" (or precisely with: .hide() ). Is there a way to pull this off without introducing additional variable, or adding a timeout?

Comment: Note that `#1` is an invalid selector. It happens to work in jQuery as long as it's on its own (whereas, say, `#1 > span` does **not** work), because jQuery doesn't use it as a selector in that case (instead it strips off the `#` and uses `getElementById`), but it doesn't work in CSS. Best to use valid selectors. While you *can* start an `id` with a digit (just not an ID selector), it's simpler to select them if you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is still visible while it's being faded out. You could set a data property to tell yourself it's in the process of disappearing:

```
$("#1").hide("slow", function() {
    $(this).removeData("hiding");
}).data("hiding", true);

// ...
var one = $("#1");
if (one.is(":hidden") || one.data("hiding")) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This looks like interesting solution, will try it out in few mins

Comment: Works like a charm.